# Redmine Base URI /redmine with nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redmine

I want to do exactly that but with nginx server
I wrote below settings but login pages like /redmine/login redirects to /login

Please assist.

```
location /redmine {
          proxy_pass        http://localhost:3000/;
          proxy_redirect    default;
          proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
          proxy_cache       dhis;
          fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;
}
```

What should I add so any link in the returned page to point start with /redmine prefix.

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but [this page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI) suggests adding

```
alias   <PATH_TO>/redmine/public;
try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
```

to your `location` block.  Does that help any?